# setting a users privilege level

Tags: cisco, switch

Is it possible to set the privilege level of my account on a cisco switch from level 1 to level 15? if so, what command should i use?

I also have the enable password for the switch.

Comment: How is your user configured? As a local user or from an external AAA source (like a radius server)

Comment: I'm a local user.

Comment: then @Everton 's answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats can only be done by an user with more priviledges than you, it´s like root user and normal users, root can change what a normal user see. But if you have the enable password,.. you can try.

By the way, the command is:

```
username "your_user" privilege privilege-level
```

Also, you can see more info here:http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/security/command/reference/fsecur_r/srfpass.html

Comment: Note that you need to set the authentication requirement for line line you're using (console or vty) to "login local" (just plain "login"--the default on vtys--means you have to configure a line-specific password). Furthermore, this is only the case if you're using default AAA; if not, you'll have to study the various AAA commands and set them up properly.

Comment: @ ebohlman Whe need to suppose that the person who is asking know the different authetication methods on switches and routers, i only gives to him the command line need, cause if he has an account, he know hoy can handled with that

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a privilege level to a local user account:

```
enable
conf t
username bob privilege 15 secret XXX
exit
write
```